# Animate number by incrementing and decrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to do some **number animation** in some `div` value, the issue is that the animation start each time from `0` but I don't want this, I want that it to start from the previous value.

**Example:**
If I enter `10`, animation starts from `0` and goes to `10`. If I then change the `10` to `8`, I want the animation to go from `10` to `8` and not from `0` to `8` again. Basically, it should increment or decrement from the previous value entered!

Other think, if I enter some float e.g. `0.10`, it displays `1` and I want it to display the exact value.

Thanks

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sz2fv0cp/5/)

```js
/*numbers values*/
$('.num').bind('change paste keyup', function() {
  var v1 = $(this).val();
  $('.price').html(v1);
  animatePrince();
});


/*numbers animation*/
function animatePrince() {
  $('.price').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', $(this).val()).animate({
      Counter: jQuery(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        jQuery(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.s1 {
  display: block;
}

.s2 {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.num {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 20px;
}

.price {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  padding: 20px 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="s1">Input</span>
<input class="num" type="float" value="1">
<span class="s2">Result</span>
<span class="price"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you update your jQuery section to the below mentioned code:

```
function isFloat(n){
    return Number(n) === n && n % 1 !== 0;
}

function isInt(n){
    return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;
}

/*numbers values*/
$('.num').bind('change paste keyup', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
  if(isInt(parseFloat(value)))
  {
    animatePrinceInt(parseInt(value));
  }
  else {
    animatePrinceFloat(parseFloat(value));
  }
});

/*numbers animation*/
function animatePrinceFloat(value) {
$('.price').val(value);

$({countNum1: $('.price').text()})
  .animate({countNum1: value }, {
  duration: 3000,
  easing:'linear',
  step: function() {
    var nn= this.countNum1;
    $('.price').text(parseFloat(nn).toFixed(2));
  },
  complete: function() {
    var nn= this.countNum1;
    $('.price').text(parseFloat(nn).toFixed(2));
  }
});

}

/*numbers animation*/
function animatePrinceInt(value) {
$('.price').val(value);

$({countNum: $('.price').text()})
  .animate({countNum: value}, {
  duration: 3000,
  easing:'linear',
  step: function() {
    var nn= this.countNum;
    $('.price').text(Math.floor(nn));
  },
  complete: function() {
    var nn= this.countNum;
    $('.price').text(Math.floor(nn));
  }
});

}
```

Please update the value of `duration`. I have used it as 3000 to see the animation.

Comment: It's works but not with a float exemple if you enter `0.29`, it output `1` like I said in the question I want exactly the same value as the input entred

Comment: In that case, you need to remove `Math.ceil()` from `step` and `complete`, as it is rounding-off the numeric values. Make sure to use precision in floating point values.

Comment: without the `Math.ceil()` in `step` and `complete` I have a bad output durring the animation something like this : ` 14.076421333333336 ` but the result is exactly like what i have entred, just this little issue diring the animation

Comment: Please try this `parseFloat((this.countNum).toFixed(2))`

Comment: sorry but it's not really good, look as your last update, if you enter `8`, he animate it to `8.00`, I want when i enter an `Int` he animate it to an `Int`, if   i enter an `Float` he animate it to an `float` not  when i enter an `Int`, he animate it to an `float`

Comment: For that, you need to add a check on the value, and replace the parseFloat() to parseInt where number is an int.

Comment: I tried this test but it output always that is a float `$('.num').bind('change paste keyup', function(){
    var v1 = $(this).val();
  $('.price').val(v1);
    if(typeof v1 === 'number') {
    alert('is a int');
}else {
 alert('is an float');
}
  animatePrince(v1);
});`

Comment: Please use the latest code. I've just updated it. It works fine with `float` as well as `int` values. Please test it. And, please make sure to mark it as the correct answer for your question. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the link to my JSFiddle change: http://jsfiddle.net/sz2fv0cp/244/

Comment: Thank you very much @thisisbobbs I know I was a bit boring but that's what I want now, great job

Answer (score 2):

I have done some changes in our fiddle.It works fine.

Script:

```
$('.num').on('change', function() {
    var v1 = $(this).val();
    animatePrince();
});


/*numbers animation*/
function animatePrince() {
    var target = parseFloat($('.prince').val());
    var number = parseFloat($('.num').val());
    console.log(number + "  " + target + " " + (number > target));
    if (number > target) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $('.prince').val(target.toFixed(1));
            if (number <= target) clearInterval(interval);
            target = parseFloat(target + 0.1)
        }, 30);
    } else {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $('.prince').val(target.toFixed(1));
            if (number >= target) clearInterval(interval);
            target = parseFloat(target - 0.1)
        }, 30);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="s1">Input</span>
<input class="num" type="float" value="1">
<span class="s2">Result</span>
<input class="prince" type="float" value="1">
```

css:

```
.s1 {
    display: block; }

.s2 {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 25px; }

.num, .prince {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 20px; }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gokulsandeep/sz2fv0cp/166/)

Comment: It's not working well, it always output un `float` even i enter `int`

Comment: Ya. If you want the animation as float then use the same code,else for int update **target = parseFloat(target - 0.1)** this line by  **target--** and **target = parseFloat(target + 0.1)** by **target++**

Comment: Thank you for your time, but the other answer of @thisisbobbs was more suitable for me

Comment: fine. But my answer will satisfy your need  " If I enter 10, animation starts from 0 and goes to 10. If I then change the 10 to 8, I want the animation to go from 10 to 8 and not from 0 to 8 again. Basically, it should increment or decrement from the previous value entered!"   Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gokulsandeep/sz2fv0cp/254/